# input effect when value is entered

Tags: html, css

I'm using a css effect for styling input field, but I have problem when the value is already entered on page load by PHP. The effect is when a user clicks on the input filed, label moves up and line is highlighted for text input.

How can I detect that value already exists and apply the css formating so the label is not applied over the value on page load?

This is css I'm using:

```css
input[type="text"]{
      color: #333;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    :focus{
      outline: none !important;
    
    }
    
    .col-effect{
      float: left !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      margin: 10px 3px !important;
      position: relative !important;
    }
    /* necessary to give position: relative to parent. */
    
    .effect-17{
      border: 0 !important;
      padding: 4px 0 !important;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc !important;
      background-color: transparent !important;
    }
    
    .effect-17 ~ .focus-border{
      position: absolute !important;
      bottom: 0 !important;
      left: 50% !important;
      width: 0  !important;
      height: 2px !important;
      background-color: #00838f !important;
      transition: 0.4s !important;
    }
    
    .effect-17:focus ~ .focus-border,
    .has-content.effect-17 ~ .focus-border{
      width: 100% !important;
      transition: 0.4s !important;
      left: 0 !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
    
    .effect-17 ~ label{
      position: absolute !important;
      left: 0 !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      top: 9px !important;
      color: #aaa !important;
      transition: 0.3s !important;
      letter-spacing: 0.5px !important;
    }
    
    .effect-17:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-17 ~ label{
      top: -16px !important;
      font-size: 12px !important;
      color: #00838f !important;
      transition: 0.3s !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-effect input-effect">
               <input class="form-control required fcs effect-17" id="broj_ponude" name="broj_ponude" type="text" value="<?php echo $broj_ponude['broj_dokumenta']; ?>" readonly />
               <label for="broj_ponude">
               Broj ponude
               <span class="danger"> * </span>
               </label>
               <span class="focus-border"></span>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

You can see an example on the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/novice_user/adnezp8j/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so no answers to this post. I was able to find a solution to the issue I had. Posting the answer for anyone who will come across this.

Solution is adding this to the css:

```
input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  left: 0;
  top: -16px !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #00838f;
}
```